# On Postback placeholder controls disappearing

Tags: vb.net, user-controls, ispostback

Within my webpage I am loading usercontrols within a placeholder. Each of these user controls triggers a postback when an ajaxcontroltoolkit rating is changed. The problem I am having is that if I use

```
If (Not IsPostBack is Nothing)
```

the controls within the placeholder disappear on post.

My Page_Load looks like this currently

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Session("ProId") = Nothing
    Session("FolId") = Nothing
    Dim ProId As Integer
    If (Not Request.QueryString("ProjectID") Is Nothing) Then
        ProId = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString("ProjectID").ToString())
        Session("ProId") = Request.QueryString("ProjectID").ToString()
    End If
    Dim FolId As Integer
    If (Not Request.QueryString("FolderID") Is Nothing) Then
        FolId = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString("FolderID").ToString())
        Session("FolId") = Request.QueryString("FolderID").ToString()
    End If
    objUser = New BSSiteUser(CInt(Page.User.SiteUser.intID))
    objProject = New BSProject(ProId)
    objFolder = New BSFolder(objUser.SiteUserID, FolId)
    objOrganization = New BSOrganization(objProject.intOrganizationID, objUser.SiteUserID)
    Me.Load_SubcontractorList()
    Me.Load_EvaluationList(1)
    Me.Load_EvaluationList(2)
    Me.lblorganization.Text = objOrganization.CompanyName
    Me.lblprojectname.Text = objProject.strProjectName
    Me.lblprojectnumber.Text = objProject.strProjectNumber
    Me.lbldatecreated.Text = Date.Now.Date.ToString()
End Sub
```

The Load_EvaluationList is what loads the user controls, if I place the IsPostBack check around those two, the controls disappear, what could be the problem

Answer (score -4, accepted):

I am abandoning this question as a decision was made to go a different route

Answer (score 3):

Dynamically added controls disappear on postback as you are working with a brand new instance of your page. In order for you to keep them you are going to have to recreate them for any postback that occurs.

It is also important to note that if you want your ViewState to be retained you should create your user controls on Page Init and not Page Load as loading of ViewState data back to the controls happens before the Load event.

Comment: I tried putting most of the load into Page_Init, but the ajax rating control keeps getting reset. Am i missing something. I understand the postback issue

Comment: Are you saving the CurrentRating property of the rating control to a viewstate and then setting it back on postback?

Comment: I am using the CallbackResult of the rating control which sets the value  like     Protected Sub pntrating_Changed(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As AjaxControlToolkit.RatingEventArgs)
        e.CallbackResult = e.Value
        OnBubbleCalculate(e)
    End Sub

Comment: I don't think a callback is how you are going to preserve the value. Look here for two solutions to your problem: https://lancezhang.wordpress.com/2008/11/10/create-rating-dynamically/

Comment: it works if the rating control autopostback is set to false, but unfortunately I need it to retain the value on a postback. The issue is there willnot be just one rating control on the page, there can be numerous rating controls

Comment: since the controls are reloading again, the hidden control is one of the solutions is being reset also.

Comment: The hidden control should be keeping its value on postback. Just don't create it dynamically.

Comment: well maybe I hsould of added, that the rating controls are within a repeater as well, so they have to be created again

Answer (score 0):

If you are dynamically adding controls then on every postback you have to add control again.

try using if(Not IsPostBack) or (IsPostBack) instead of comparing it with Nothing.

Here I am simply adding a textbox dynamically on postback and it will stay in every postback.

```
     Partial Class _Default
        Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

      Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If (IsPostBack) Then
        Dim t As TextBox = New TextBox()
        form1.Controls.Add(t)

    End If

End Sub
```

End Class

You can put the controls you are trying to add dynamically in one function/method/subroutine and just call inside of Load.

## Update

If you want your data to stay in the controls you have to save the data in the viewstate. You will have to create control again no matter what but before control is sent back to user get their data from the view state. It is described with example here.

http://forums.asp.net/t/1186195.aspx/1

Comment: You can also do it in pre init method.

Comment: That is the thing I dont want the controls to reload everytime. I want them to stay on the screen on postback. I do not want to reload them every time the page makes a round trip. if I set it in pre_init or page_load with if (Not IsPostBack) everything gets cleared and they never get reloaded

Comment: I know what you are saying that you want the controls data as it is, you can achieve that by saving the control state in the viewstate. I have given the example link above.

Comment: there is way too much data to use view state. Each of the controls is a user control that can be repeated numerous times and within itself.

Comment: Either I am just really stupid or I dont know, but since these contorls are loaded dynamically I do not know how I would go about storing the data for each rating control especially if there is 10 or more